# Erreur Google speech to text Stremaing

Tags: streaming, google-speech-to-text-api

I am testing "Google Speech to text" (with StreamingRecognize()) and the code doesn't work at all. I have an error message as following:

"
Unhandled exception. Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="OutOfRange", Detail="Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real time.")
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.AsyncResponseStream`1.MoveNextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Utilisateur\source\repos\VoiceText070923\VoiceText070923\Program.cs:line 48
at Program.(String[] args)

Sortie de C:\Users\Utilisateur\source\repos\VoiceText070923\VoiceText070923\bin\Debug\net6.0\VoiceText070923.exe (processus 26408). Code : -532462766.
Appuyez sur une touche pour fermer cette fenêtre. . .
"
and also attached screenshot of my code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZMdg.png)

Could you help me, please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please could you paste your code in a code block within your question rather than using a screenshot. Also, I think the error is pretty clear. It seems either intentionally, or due to an encoding delay perhaps, you are waiting too long before sending audio after opening the stream. Posting the code will allow others to make edits and give you a better resolution.